# AJAX form submission not reloading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have seen quite a few questions and answers on here but none seem to fix my issue. I have a form which is loaded from a ajax load call into a div class called dynamic-content. Basically if the form submit button is pressed I want it to reload this form in ajax so that it does the php form validation. My issue is that when the submit occurs I call the ajax load to reload via javascript but it is not triggering and instead its just going back to the current index page. My JS is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Handle AJAX request from sidebar buttons
var trigger = $('.submit-btn'),
    container = $('.dynamic-content');

  $(".add-customer-form-btn").submit(function() {
    // do something...
    alert('test');

    container.load('customers/customersaddform.php',$("form").serializeArray());

    return false;
  });

});
```

my html form in customersaddform.php which is loaded into dynamic-content div in located main index file.

```
<?php 
//FORM VALIDATION CHECKS
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-field add-customer-form">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
        <h4>Account Information</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 label-container">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name" required/>
                        <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                        <div class="input-error-msg"><?php echo $first_name_err;?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=col-md-12 label-container">
                        <input type="submit" class="add-customer-form-btn submit-btn" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `load` method does not load data because when you click on `button` your page `reload` your `container` always empty need to convert in `ajax` call.

Comment: How could the container variable empty though despite the ajax call is for dynamic content which is the variable container? Could you show me how to fix this because I do not think I understand. Thanks!